# VS2015 test explorer tests dont show up

Tags: visual-studio-2015, nunit, mstest

No matter what I try and do I can not get my tests (Both MSTest and nUnit) to show up in VS 2015 Enterprise Test Explorer.

I have tested this with 2 separate projects (one I was working on where I first noticed the issue) as well as a simple console app that I created just to make sure that Tests were working.

This is definitely something specific to my machine as I copied both projects over to another machine and opened them there (in VS 2015 Pro) and all the tests show up in both projects.

Something is broken in Test Explorer and I can not figure out what it is.

I have tried running VS as an administrator, tried clearing out the temp folder and still nothing.  Also made sure that all projects are set to compile as AnyCPU and the tried targeting the tests at both X86 and X64.

I would prefer not having to run tests on a separate machine and would preferably not reinstall VS but this is starting to seem like the only option (if I knew it would work I would probably already have done it).

Any suggestions on other steps to try?

Comment: In the case of NUnit, have you actually installed the correct nunit adapter? There's one for v2 and one for v3.

Comment: @Charlie yup, got the V3 adapter installed and tested that everything works on the "other" machine. I did manage to get the tests to show up on my normal box once but then after a restart of VS they disappeared again.

Comment: Try nuking the hidden .vs folder (should be in the same directory as the solution) it's where Studio keeps user specific stuff, may get you out of your hole. (Close Studio first)